# How to get the 4 corners X, Y coordinates value of a FabricJS rectangle

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, fabricjs

I'm trying to make a tool to draw shapes over an image and I need to save the drawing state in my database in JSON format. I can easily create a shape using the below and use the FabricJS JSON exporter:

```
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  fill: 'rgba(51, 152, 219, 0.3)',
  width: 20,
  height: 20
});
```

But the problem is in the JSON data FabricJS only keeps the track of the `top-left` corner `X, Y` coordinates. But I need to get all 4 corners coordinates `X, Y` value and 2 corners coordinate data for a `line` shape.

Note: Shape may have a different angle than `90`

Comment: top right = x + width, bottom left = y + height

Comment: Does FabricJs keeps the track of the width and height ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan this method won't work with shapes with a different angle than 90 degrees.

Comment: @trixo Yes FabricJS keeps track of the width and height, but since shapes can have a different angle than 90 degrees simply adding x+width and y+height won't work. Can use math though but I wanted to know if is there anything FabricJS offers out of the box.

Comment: @MDRobinIslam that is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try `oCoords`/`aCoords` ?

This property should return all the corners with applying rotation

http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Rect.html#oCoords

http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Rect.html#aCoords

**Update**

As you want to store the coordinates to retrieve and draw rectangle back from db data then I think it is better to store not 4 corner coords but left,top,width,height,angle,?scale. So that you can create rectangle depending on this properties. If you need it not for Fabricjs usage then you can use `oCoords` that I've mentioned before.

`getCoords` method is also the option to use

http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Rect.html#getCoords

Comment: Thank you very much! `getCoords` is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use [toJSON](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#toJSON) to serialize and [loadFromJSON](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#loadFromJSON) to load json data in canvas.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var json;
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  fill: 'rgba(51, 152, 219, 0.3)',
  width: 50,
  height: 50
});
canvas.add(rect);

function onSave(){
  json = canvas.toJSON();
}

function onLoad(){
 if(!json) return
 canvas.loadFromJSON(json,function(){
   canvas.requestRenderAll();
 })
}
```

```css
canvas{
 border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.5/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id='c' width=400 height=400></canvas>
<button onclick='onSave()'>save</button>
<button onclick='onLoad()'>load</button>
```